# UnitTest for SharePoint.EventListener with TaxonomyField

Tags: 2010, event-receivers, taxonomy, unit-testing

Recently, I tried to write a unit test for my new SharePoint project. The Project contains EventListener which checks a TaxonomyField in a special list, and fill it, if field is empty.

Code looks like this:

```
public class CategoryListener: SPItemEventReceiver
{
    ...
    public override void ItemCheckedIn(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList mediaLib = web.Lists[properties.ListId];
            SPListItem checkInItem = mediaLib.Items[properties.ListItemId];

            if (checkInItem[cfg.CategoryField.Id] != null)
                return;

            Term categoryTerm = TermManager.GetAssociatedTerm(checkInItem, cfg.CategoryField);

            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            cfg.CategoryField.SetFieldValue(checkInItem, categoryTerm); 
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
        }
    }
    ...
}

public class Configuration
{
    public Guid MediaLibraryId { get; set; }
    public TaxonomyField CategoryField { get; set; }
    public bool AutocreateCategory { get; set; }

    public static Configuration Load()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

And I want to write unit test with Microsoft.Moles and SharePoint.Behaviour.

I try:

```
namespace Test.FullLibName
{
    [TestClass]
    public class CategoryListenerTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [HostType("Moles")]
        public void CategoryListener_ItemCheckIn_UpdateCategory()
        {
            var bSPList = new BSPList();
            bSPList.ID = new Guid("98b23464-b026-4525-bd22-6b590bd3abfe");
            bSPList.Title = "ListTitle";

            var bSPItem = bSPList.Items.SetOne();
            bSPItem.ID = 1;

            ??? categoryField = new ???();

            MConfiguration.Load = delegate()
            {
                return new Configuration()
                {
                    CategoryField = categoryField,
                    MediaLibraryId = new Guid("c3948036-778c-4064-bd40-c029139efeca")
                };
            };

            CategoryListener listener = new CategoryListener();
            ListLog log = new ListLog();
            listener.Log = log;

            var fProperties = new BSPItemEventProperties();
            fProperties.ListTitle = bSPList.Title;
            fProperties.ListId = bSPList.ID;
            fProperties.ListItemId = 1;

            listener.ItemCheckedIn(fProperties);

            /// Asserts
        }
    }
}
```

How I can test it?